# I am not sure how to open a video on the product page of opencart using their built in colorbox?

Tags: colorbox, opencart

I am new to both opencart and colorbox so excuse my ignorance here.  I was wanting to add a 'Demo' link on the category pages to open up the colorbox for either video on youtube or local swf files.
It is opening the youtube video up and the swf file but not in the colorbox - here is the code that I have entered in the description area (youtube).

```html
<link href="colorbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
<p><a class="colorbox cboxElement" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/xrwLTvg22VI">Click
 Here to see a Demo of Whaikorero Maori.</a></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it is said only

> Supports photos, grouping, slideshow, ajax, inline, and iframed content.

at [ColorBox homepage](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox), at examples page we can see section with [other content types](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/) (Video/Flash), where the code is as follows:

**HTML**

```html
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/v/VOJyrQa_WR4?rel=0&amp;wmode=transparent" class="youtube cboxElement">Flash / Video (Iframe/Direct Link To YouTube)</a>
```

**JS**

```js
$(".youtube").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:640, innerHeight:390});
```

I guess the anchor's class `cboxElement` does the magic (without that class the link opens to new window)...